# Is it possible to DM someone with their user ID?

Tags: discord.js

I want to make it so you can pass someone's user ID into some args instead of mentioning them.
I am not sure how to pass it through that way, I have only figured out how to do it with mentioning them.

How can I do this?
Sorry I have not given any code but could someone be nice to tell me how to do it please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that you have defined `args` and `client` already. If you named this variables differently, just change the names.

This is how you could make it:

```js
let user = client.users.cache.get(args[0]);
user.send("Hello World!");
```

Usage:

```
!dm <User ID>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code can put in your code without client or args, just need message

```js
message.client.users.fetch(message.content).send("Hello there!");
```